# Hyper-V error when starting docker in windows

Tags: windows, docker

I've installed docker on windows 10 machine. When I start it I get error

[image]

As it can be seen on the picture below, I have Hyper-V switched on as on in the windows features, so not sure what is wrong. Anyone can advise please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the issue. I did face same issue on my desktop than I switched from Hyper-V to WSL 2. and it worked. Below link could be useful for you.

[Docker for Windows-WSL](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/)